# JSF para enviar un correo con Java Send Mail

Tags: jsf

El error es este:

```
> ADVERTENCIA:   /paginas/correo/correo.xhtml @52,102
> target="#{correoControlador.enviar}": The class
> 'com.pigbreding.modelo.ManageBeans.CorreoControlador' does not have
> the property 'enviar'. javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException:
> /paginas/correo/correo.xhtml @52,102
> target="#{correoControlador.enviar}": The class
> 'com.pigbreding.modelo.ManageBeans.CorreoControlador' does not have
> the property 'enviar'.    at
> com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getType(TagValueExpression.java:88)
>   at
> com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.core.SetPropertyActionListenerHandler$SetPropertyListener.processAction(SetPropertyActionListenerHandler.java:200)
>   at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:96)
>   at
> javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:514)
>   at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:235)    at
> javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:871)
>   at
> javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1419)
>   at
> com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:82)
>   at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:100)    at
> com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:201)
>   at
> javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.executeLifecyle(FacesServlet.java:731)
>   at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:475)   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1622)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:258)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:654)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:593)
>   at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:159)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:371)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:238)
>   at
> com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:516)
>   at
> com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:213)
>   at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
>   at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
>   at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:242)
>   at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
>   at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
>   at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
>   at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
>   at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
>   at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
>   at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:539)
>   at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
>   at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
>   at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
>   at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
>   at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:593)
>   at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:573)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
> javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: The class
> 'com.pigbreding.modelo.ManageBeans.CorreoControlador' does not have
> the property 'enviar'.    at
> javax.el.BeanELResolver.getBeanProperty(BeanELResolver.java:731)  at
> javax.el.BeanELResolver.getType(BeanELResolver.java:301)  at
> com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getType(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:220)
>   at
> com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getType(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:248)
>   at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getType(AstValue.java:92)     at
> com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getType(ValueExpressionImpl.java:201)
>   at
> org.jboss.weld.module.web.el.WeldValueExpression.getType(WeldValueExpression.java:93)
>   at
> com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getType(TagValueExpression.java:86)
>   ... 39 more
> 
> FATAL:   JSF1073: se ha interceptado javax.faces.FacesException
> durante el procesamiento de INVOKE_APPLICATION 5 :
> UIComponent-ClientId=, Mensaje=/paginas/correo/correo.xhtml @52,102
> target="#{correoControlador.enviar}": The class
> 'com.pigbreding.modelo.ManageBeans.CorreoControlador' does not have
> the property 'enviar'. FATAL:   /paginas/correo/correo.xhtml @52,102
> target="#{correoControlador.enviar}": The class
> 'com.pigbreding.modelo.ManageBeans.CorreoControlador' does not have
> the property 'enviar'. javax.faces.FacesException:
> /paginas/correo/correo.xhtml @52,102
> target="#{correoControlador.enviar}": The class
> 'com.pigbreding.modelo.ManageBeans.CorreoControlador' does not have
> the property 'enviar'.    at
> com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:90)
>   at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:100)    at
> com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:201)
>   at
> javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.executeLifecyle(FacesServlet.java:731)
>   at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:475)   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1622)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:258)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:654)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:593)
>   at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:159)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:371)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:238)
>   at
> com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:516)
>   at
> com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:213)
>   at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
>   at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
>   at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:242)
>   at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
>   at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
>   at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
>   at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
>   at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
>   at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
>   at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:539)
>   at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
>   at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
>   at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
>   at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
>   at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:593)
>   at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:573)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
> javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /paginas/correo/correo.xhtml
> @52,102 target="#{correoControlador.enviar}": The class
> 'com.pigbreding.modelo.ManageBeans.CorreoControlador' does not have
> the property 'enviar'.    at
> com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getType(TagValueExpression.java:88)
>   at
> com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.core.SetPropertyActionListenerHandler$SetPropertyListener.processAction(SetPropertyActionListenerHandler.java:200)
>   at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:96)
>   at
> javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:514)
>   at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:235)    at
> javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:871)
>   at
> javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1419)
>   at
> com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:82)
>   ... 32 more Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: The class
> 'com.pigbreding.modelo.ManageBeans.CorreoControlador' does not have
> the property 'enviar'.    at
> javax.el.BeanELResolver.getBeanProperty(BeanELResolver.java:731)  at
> javax.el.BeanELResolver.getType(BeanELResolver.java:301)  at
> com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getType(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:220)
>   at
> com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getType(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:248)
>   at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getType(AstValue.java:92)     at
> com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getType(ValueExpressionImpl.java:201)
>   at
> org.jboss.weld.module.web.el.WeldValueExpression.getType(WeldValueExpression.java:93)
>   at
> com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getType(TagValueExpression.java:86)
>   ... 39 more
```

El html es este

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
                xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
                template="/WEB-INF/template/main-form.xhtml"
                xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
                xmlns:a="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough">

    <ui:define name="estilos">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="#{request.contextPath}/resources/css/porquinansa.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="#{request.contextPath}/resources/css/rpt-cerdo.css"/>
    </ui:define>
    <ui:define name="contenido">


        <h1 class="titulomenu col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12">Enviar Correo
        </h1>

        <h:form class="container" id="frmAsignaTareas" >

            <div class="form-group">



                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <h:outputLabel class="control-label" for="destinatario" value="Para"> 
                    </h:outputLabel>

                    <h:inputText    class="form-control" 
                                   value="#{correoControlador.destinatario}" />
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <h:outputLabel class="control-label" for="asunto" value="Asunto"> 
                    </h:outputLabel>

                    <h:inputText   class="form-control" 
                                   value="#{correoControlador.asunto}" />
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <h:outputLabel class="control-label" for="cuerpo" value="Mensaje"> 
                    </h:outputLabel>

                    <h:inputTextarea    class="form-control" 
                                       value="#{correoControlador.cuerpo}" />
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <h:commandButton type="submit" class="btn btn-dark btn-lg btn-block " value="Enviar" action="#{correoControlador.enviar()}">
                        
                    </h:commandButton>
                </div>
            </div>
        </h:form>
    </ui:define>
    <ui:define name="scripts-propios">
        <script src="resources/js/scripts.js"></script>
    </ui:define>

</ui:composition>
```

El controlador de Mail es este

```
package com.pigbreding.modelo.ManageBeans;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.BodyPart;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Multipart;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;

public class MailControlador {

    private final static String KEY_SMTP_SERVER = "mail.smtp.host";
    private final static String KEY_FROM = "mail.smtp.user";
    private final static String KEY_PASSWORD = "mail.smtp.password";

    private static Properties props;

    private static void loadConfig() {
        if (props == null) {

            props = new Properties();
            props.put(KEY_SMTP_SERVER, "smtp.gmail.com"); //El servidor SMTP de google 
            props.put(KEY_FROM, "CORREO"); //Correo desde vamos a enviar el correo
            props.put(KEY_PASSWORD, "CLAVE");//la clave de la cuenta de correo desde donde se enviara el correo
            props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");//Usar autenticacion mediante usuario y clave
            props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", "smtp.gmail.com");
            props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");// para conectar de manera segura al servidor SMTP
            props.put("mail.smtp.port", "25"); //el puerto smtp seguro de google, el puerto por default es el 25

        }
    }

    public static void sendMail(String destinatario, String asunto, String cuerpo) {
        loadConfig();
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

        try {
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(props.getProperty(KEY_FROM)));
            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    new InternetAddress(destinatario));//Se podrian añadir varios de la misma manera
            message.setSubject(asunto);
            message.setText(cuerpo);
            
            Transport trans = session.getTransport("smtp");
            trans.connect(props.getProperty(KEY_SMTP_SERVER),
                    props.getProperty(KEY_FROM),
                    props.getProperty(KEY_PASSWORD));
            trans.sendMessage(message,message.getAllRecipients());
            trans.close();
        } catch (MessagingException  me) {
            me.printStackTrace(); //Si se produce error
            
        }
      
      
       
    }
    public static void sendMailHTML(String destinatarios, String asuntos, String cuerpoHTML) {
        loadConfig();
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

        try {
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(props.getProperty(KEY_FROM)));
            message.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,destinatarios);
            message.setSubject(asuntos);
            Multipart parts = new MimeMultipart();
            BodyPart bodyMail = new MimeBodyPart();
            bodyMail.setContent(cuerpoHTML, "text/html");
            parts.addBodyPart(bodyMail);
            message.setContent(parts);
            Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
            transport.connect(props.getProperty(KEY_SMTP_SERVER),
                    props.getProperty(KEY_FROM),
                    props.getProperty(KEY_PASSWORD));
            transport.sendMessage(message,message.getAllRecipients());
            transport.close();
        } catch (MessagingException  me) {
            me.printStackTrace(); //Si se produce error
            
        }
      
        
       
    }
    
     public static void sendMailHTML(String destinatarios, String asuntos, String cuerpoHTML, List<File> files) throws IOException {
        loadConfig();
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

        try {
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(props.getProperty(KEY_FROM)));
            message.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,destinatarios);
            message.setSubject(asuntos);
            Multipart parts = new MimeMultipart();
            BodyPart bodyMail = new MimeBodyPart();
            bodyMail.setContent(cuerpoHTML, "text/html");
            parts.addBodyPart(bodyMail);
            for (File file : files){
                MimeBodyPart attached = new MimeBodyPart();
                attached.attachFile(file);
                parts.addBodyPart(attached);   
            }
            message.setContent(parts);
            Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
            transport.connect(props.getProperty(KEY_SMTP_SERVER),
                    props.getProperty(KEY_FROM),
                    props.getProperty(KEY_PASSWORD));
            transport.sendMessage(message,message.getAllRecipients());
            transport.close();
        } catch (MessagingException  me) {
            me.printStackTrace(); //Si se produce error
            
        }  
    }
    }
```

Y donde tengo el controlador para hacer el método de enviar es este

```
    /*
     * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
     * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
     * and open the template in the editor.
     */
    package com.pigbreding.modelo.ManageBeans;
    
    import java.io.Serializable;
    import javax.inject.Named;
    import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped;
    
    /**
     *
     * @author jennt_000
     */
    @Named(value = "correoControlador")
    @ViewScoped
    public class CorreoControlador implements Serializable {

    /*private String from;*/
    private String destinatario;
    private String asunto;
    private String cuerpo;

    public CorreoControlador() {
    }

    /*public String getFrom() {
        return from;
    }

    public void setFrom(String from) {
        this.from = from;
    }*/
    public String getAsunto() {
        return asunto;
    }

    public void setAsunto(String asunto) {
        this.asunto = asunto;
    }

    public String getDestinatario() {
        return destinatario;
    }

    public void setDestinatario(String destinatario) {
        this.destinatario = destinatario;
    }

    public String getCuerpo() {
        return cuerpo;
    }

    public void setCuerpo(String cuerpo) {
        this.cuerpo = cuerpo;
    }

    public String enviar() {
        try {
            System.out.println(destinatario);
            System.out.println(asunto);
            System.out.println(cuerpo);
            MailControlador mailControlador = new MailControlador();
            mailControlador.sendMail(destinatario, asunto, cuerpo);

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return null;
    }
    }
```

Comment: El controlador de Mail le borre la contraseña y correo por razones de seguridad, ya que este es un sitio publico. Gracias

Answer (score 1):

El error que veo en el stacktrace es

> /paginas/correo/correo.xhtml @52,102 target="#{correoControlador.enviar}": The class 'com.pigbreding.modelo.ManageBeans.CorreoControlador' does not have the property 'enviar'. javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /paginas/correo/correo.xhtml @52,102 target="#{correoControlador.enviar}": The class 'com.pigbreding.modelo.ManageBeans.CorreoControlador' does not have the property 'enviar'.

Esto se da típicamente cuando queremos mostrar un atributo de nuestro bean y no existe el respectivo getter de dicho atributo. Veo que el error se dá en la vista **correo.xhtml**. El fragmento de xhtml que pegaste, ¿Pertenece al archivo que te digo?